# how to fix tuple problem in python gcse nea project music game

Tags: python, authentication, tuples

When running the code in python it comes up with multiple errors have no clue how to fix it if someone can it would be much appreciated

code for a music quiz game the error resides on lines which are meant to split the contents of the txt file into song name and artist

the txt file is formatted as such

song,song artist

```
AuthUsers = {"drew":"pw","masif":"pw","ishy":"pw"}
#authentication
PWLoop = True

while PWLoop:
    userName = input("what is your username?")
#asking for password
    password = (input("what is the password?"))

    if userName in AuthUsers:
        if AuthUsers.get(userName) == password:
            print("you are allowed to play")
            PWLoop = False
        else:
            print("invalid password")
    else:
        print("invalid username")


#GAME

#SETTING SCORE VARIBLE
score = 0

#READING SONGS

read = open("SONGS.txt", "r")
songs = read.readline()
songlist = []

for i in range(len(songs)):
    songlist.append(songs[i].strip())



while x == 0:
    #RANDOMLY CHOSING A SONG

    choice = random.choice(songlist)
    artist, song = choice.split()


#SPLITTING INTO FIRST WORDS

songs = song.split()
letters = [word[0] for word in songs]


#LOOP

for x in range(0,2):
    print(artist, "".join(letters))
    guess= str(input(Fore.RED + "guess the song"))
    if guess == song:
        if x == 0:
            score = score + 2
            break
        if x == 1:
            score = score + 1
            break
```

code should display login

then game

but instead 
displays login

then error

the lines affected should split the txt file into the first letter of the song and artist

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: I don't understand it if you run it in python 3.4 you should find out

Comment: Or you could run it and copy and paste the error here so that everyone who might be able to help can see it. The easier you make it for people to help you, the more likely they are to do so!

Comment: Will do in two day when my computer is repaired